# glReadPixels doesnt work for the first left click

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl, mfc

I am working on a MFC app which is a MDI. One of the child frame uses OpenGL(mixed with fixed function and modern version) called 3d view and another child frame uses GDI called plan view. Both of the views use the same doc.

The 3d view has a function to detect if the mouse cursor is over rendered 3d model by reading pixels and check its depth value.

The function is used for WM_MOUSEMOVE and WM_LBUTTONDOWN events. Most time it works pretty well. But it failed when I move my cursor from the plan view(currently active) to the 3d view and left mouse click. The depth values read from the pixels(called from onLButtonDown) are always all zeros though it is over a model. There is no OpenGL error reported. It only fails on the first mouse click when the 3d view is not activated. Afterwards, everything works well again.

The issue doesn't happen on all machines. And it happens to me but not to another guy with the same hardware machine with me. Is that possible hardware related or a code bug?

Things tried:

- I tried to increase the pixel block size much bigger but depths are still all zero.
- If I click on the title bar of the 3d view to activate it first, then works.
- I tried to set the 3d view active and foreground in the onLButtonDown method before reading pixels. But still failed.(btw, the 3d view should be active already before the OnLButtonDown handler via other message handler fired by the left button down).
- I tried to invalidate rect before reading pixels, failed too.

The code is as below:

```
BOOL CMy3DView::IsOverModel(int x0, int y0, int &xM, int &yM, GLfloat &zWin, int width0 , int height0  )
{
    
    int width = max(1,width0);
    int height= max(1,height0);
         

    CRect RectView;
    GetClientRect(&RectView);
    GLint realy = RectView.Height() - 1 - (GLint)y0 ; /*  OpenGL y coordinate position  */

    std::vector<GLfloat> z(width*height);

    //Read the window z co-ordinates the z value of the points in a rectangle of width*height  )
    xM = max(0, x0-(width-1)/2);
    yM = max(0, realy-(height-1)/2);
    glReadPixels(xM, yM, (GLsizei)width, (GLsizei)height, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &z[0]);  OutputGlError(_T("glReadPixels")) ;
    

    /* check pixels along concentric, nested boxes around the central point   */
    for (int k=0; k<=(min(height,width)-1)/2; ++k){
        for (int i=-k;i<=k;++i){
            xM = x0+i;
            for (int j=-k;j<=k;++j){
                if (abs(i)==k || abs(j)==k) {
                    yM = realy+j;
                    zWin=z[(i+(width-1)/2)+width*(j+(height-1)/2)];
                    if (zWin<1.0-FLT_EPSILON) break;
                }
            }
            if (zWin<1.0-FLT_EPSILON) break;
        }
        if (zWin<1.0-FLT_EPSILON) break;
    }


    yM = RectView.Height() - 1 - yM;
    
    if (zWin>1.0-FLT_EPSILON || zWin<FLT_EPSILON) {// z is the depth, between 0 and 1, i.e. between Near and Far plans.  
        xM=x0; yM=y0;
        return FALSE; 
    }   
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Which buffer are you reading from? Sounds like you're reading from the back buffer (after having swapped your image to the front?) maybe try adding`glReadBuffer(GL_FRONT);` prior to the read pixels call perhaps?

Comment: @robthebloke  I am reading from to the default frame buffer. I tried to place the glReadBuffer(GL_FRONT); before reading pixels but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a solution for that: I called render(GetDC) before any processing in OnLButtonDown. somehow it fixed the issue though I don't think it's necessary.
InvalideRect wont fix the issue since it will update the view for the next WM_PAINT.

Weird, since it works for some machines without the fix. Still curious about the reason.